# Ways to implement Java IDE into a Unity game

Tags: java, ide, unity-game-engine

My goal is to design and develop a game which teaches people to program in Java.

The question is: Which possibilities are there to implement an IDE into a Unity game?

For example: [Codespells](https://sites.google.com/a/eng.ucsd.edu/codespells/home) is built with unity but implements a Java code editor in which you have some kind of code-auto-completion and a console.

I am also interested in other solutions apart from Unity, if there are some.

Kind regards

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Eclipse is an open source Java IDE for which you could develop a plugin which teaches the language.

Comment: You realize the only limiting factor is you, right? You can't make this about tools. Example: yes you could do it with the help of Unity. But if you have no experience making games/simulations with Unity and you don't know how to program extensions for it, its not going to happen. I'm sure that with enough willpower, there are people who can do this through a Minecraft mod. I certainly can't and so I wouldn't even go there. So what can -you- do? Use the tools you know.

Comment: @blalasaadri yes you could develop a "game like"-plugin, but you would need an own engine for the game then, right?

Gimby The question is just, whether there are ways to simply implement a code editor in a game engine such as provided in unity. 
I do not know any other game development tools, this is why I would like to start off with Unity.

Comment: Which part of programming in java do you want to teach your players? I wouldn't recommend trying to implement a full ide in your game. Maybe you can think of a solution that does not require you to support full programs and the complete language. (Not implementing a full ide is especially important since none of your players would eventually use your game as their primary coding environment)

Comment: @SimonGroenewolt I want to try teaching them imporved object-oriented programming, concepts of SW development, inheritance, interfaces and polymorphism, streams, generics and the use of dynamic data structures.
I absolutely see your point in not implementing the whole IDE as I just want to teach the concepts in a game-like environment and not replace their primary coding environment (which is Eclipse in this case).

Comment: BTW: This is what I did in the end: [Picture](https://photos-2.dropbox.com/t/1/AAA1Xev2H40F151RzxoD8hUGgOjaYl11LTlThxx0lEXd4g/12/47971103/png/1024x768/3/1416848400/0/2/UnityIntegration.png/M2VZAOT_mIj-p_77Cbyuh4NGvCBwO51X8vblxm8ci30) the JVM runs the compiled .java File and returns C# Code.
Server uses eval to use the returned C#-Code for the game commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend implementing some sort of Java parser written in JavaScript into your game, then coding a simple ide (some menus and a command line) to surround it.  I would use ANTLR, which is a general language parser which you can use to translate Java into Javascript to have it run in Unity.  Another option is GWT, which allows you to write applications in Java and execute them in JavaScript.  Hope you can use one of these two options, and good luck with your game.

EDIT: You could also literally start another application from within Unity if that would be useful to you. Something like the following on Mac:

```
import System.IO;

function Start() {
   var info:FileInfo = new FileInfo("/Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit");
   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(info.FullName);
}
```

Or this on Windows:

```
import System.Diagnostics;

var fileLocation: String = "C:/Program Files/Skype/Phone/Skype.exe";
var test:Process = new Process();
test.StartInfo.FileName = fileLocation;
function Start() {
   test.Start();
   UnityEngine.Debug.Log("we got here!");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As the comments said, you don't need to reinvent the wheel.
We have IDEs in the market which does the job well.

Regarding the other part of your question, designing a game to help people learn java... there is an excellent project going on, on this topic, named Alice. It is a carnegie-melon initiative.

http://www.alice.org/index.php

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_(software)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_%28software%29)

You might take a look at their source code and see if that give you some idea on your own development.

Comment: Quite right.  There are already many, many projects and indeed apps like this if you're making a Hopscotch-like thing.  Nobody uses the crap-flooded answers.unity site any more, but you can find a number of questions on there about it .. http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/7885/interpret-unityscript-at-runtime.html http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/558115/in-game-programming-consolehow-to.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could have a look at [Scintilla](http://www.scintilla.org). This is an open source multi platform text widget used in open source editors like `notepad2` or `notepad++`.